# Two classes implementing one ListnerInferface, only the first class runs events?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener

So I have the classes;

```
ControllerOne.java
```

and

```
ControllerTwo.java
```

They both `implement MyWindowListener` interface with the method `void actionHappend();`

In my View class `implementing ActionListener` I have added the windowListener to a `JButton`. And when the `actionPerformed()` is run in the view, it will check the source of the event and check if it was the button for example.

If it was the button, then the `windowListener.actionHappend();` will run, and some code in the controller will run.

The problem is now, only the first Controller "ControllerOne" that is implementing this interface seems to run the method `actionHappend();`

Question:

Cant multiple classes that implement a the same custom Listener be started in the same event?

Comment: Multiple `ActionListener`s will work fine. You need to do a little more debugging and also show your code. How exactly do you know that the second one isn't running?

Answer (score 4):

> Cant multiple classes that implement a the same custom Listener be runned in the same event?

Answer, yes they can. A single event can trigger multiples of the same listener type.

Now if you want to make my work more challenging, and my answer quality improved, ramp up the quality of your question with more detail and code.

As an aside:

- The [WindowListener interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) is already present in core Java, and as suggested by its name, it is built to listen for state changes of Swing and AWT windows such as JFrames and JDialogs.
- This interface does not have an `actionHappend()` method declared.
- I can't picture when anyone would ever add a WindowListener to a JButton. An ActionListener yes, but WindowListener, never.
- In fact, a JButton doesn't even have a an `addWindowListener(WindowListener wListener)` method.
- You state, `"in my View class implementing ActionListener..."` -- note that as a general rule, view classes should not implement listener interfaces, except in very simplistic toy programs.

Comment: I'll accept that -whatever votes, but hopefully can reverse it once we find out more from the OP.